# Let sailsJS auto update createdAt and updatedAt

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I'm trying to set up a model that has a createdAt and updatedAt column and want sails to auto update these field as the entry changes. At the moment I can't get it to work. Tried to look at the documentation but they don't provide a "guide" about how to set this up.

My files are as follow:

Users.js (Model)

```
module.exports = {
  tableName: 'users',
  primaryKey: 'id',
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type:'number',
      unique:true,
      autoIncrement:true
    },
    name: {
      type:'string'
    },
    email: {
      type:'string'
    },
    password: {
      type:'string'
    },
    profilePicture: {
      type:'longtext'
    },
    location: {
      type:'string'
    },
    createdAt: {
      type:'number'
    },
    updatedAt:{
      type: 'number'
    }

  }

};
```

config.model.js (Set migrate to safe so it won't clear the tables everytime it starts.)

```
migrate: 'safe',

attributes: {
    createdAt: { type: 'number', autoCreatedAt: true, },
    updatedAt: { type: 'number', autoUpdatedAt: true, },
    id: { type: 'number', autoIncrement: true, },
  },
```

In my database (MySQL) I have the createdAt and updatedAt columns set to DATETIME.

The table was however already present when I started with sails so I'm not sure if this stuff only work if you create the table with sails.

Comment: I had the same problem and I didnt find any solution. I think it is a known bug to waterline. My solution was, when I create my table with SQL, to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the following change in USER model

```
module.exports = {
  tableName: 'users',
  primaryKey: 'id',
 autocreatedAt : true,
autoupdatedAt : true,
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type:'number',
      unique:true,
      autoIncrement:true
    },
    name: {
      type:'string'
    },
    email: {
      type:'string'
    },
    password: {
      type:'string'
    },
    profilePicture: {
      type:'longtext'
    },
    location: {
      type:'string'
    }

  }

};
```

Answer (score 3):

To apply these to all of your tables, you can modify `module.exports.models` within `config/models.js` and add the `autoUpdatedAt` and `autoCreatedAt` properties. Also, make sure the types are consistent with how it's represented in the database. Within Sails, `createdAt` and `updatedAt` use the `datetime` type:

```
module.exports.models = {
  autoUpdatedAt: true,
  autoCreatedAt: true,

  attributes: {
    createdAt: {
      type: 'datetime',
    }
    updatedAt: {
      type: 'datetime',
    }
  }
}
```

If you decide you want the column names to be different from the default names of `updatedAt` and `createdAt`, instead of setting the values to `true`, you would set them to a string value that would be the name of the custom column.

Docs: https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/model-settings#?autocreatedat